# XHTML: No selected item in <select> despite of 'selected="selected"'

Tags: xhtml

I'm making a XHTML Page, and i'm using php to generate it. So, now I'm generating a combobox like this:

```
<select id="Indexer_Backend_select" size="1" onchange="changeHidBySelect('all_id')">
    <option value="nr1">nr1</option>
    <option value="nr2">nr2</option>
    <option value="nr3" selected="selected">nr3</option>
</select>
```

So, now, in some cases, it's working, and in some othere cases, there is just the toppest selected.

Why this? I'm seriously blockd, so I don't know at all how to go on...

thx for help

EDIT:

-I'm using Firefox

-I just wrote this everywhere, it gets generated by a PHP function which looks like this:

```
function createOptions($defaultvalue,$curr_path,$default_important,$only_modules) {

###############################################################################################
## String createOptions($defaultvalue string, $curr_path string, $default_important boolean, ##
##                      $only_modules boolean);                                              ##
##                                                                                           ##
## This function returns all the Modules which can be selected in every workflow.            ##
## The Return value is a string (the HTML-Code for the <select>-Wheel)                       ##
##                                                                                           ##
## $defaultvalue describes the preselected value. If none is set, the toppest (alphabetic    ##
## order) is selected. For more, read param $default_important...                            ##
##                                                                                           ##
## $curr_path describes the path, on which the select's ID is based.                         ##
##                                                                                           ##
## $default_important describes, if it is important to recognize, if no default-value was    ##
## given. If true, every time, no default-value was given, a little star is displayed        ##
## next to the <select>. If false, this won't be displayed.                                  ##
##                                                                                           ##
## $only_modules says, if the complete select tag or only all the <option>-Entrys should be  ##
## returned. So, if set to true, only a list of <option>-Tags will be returned.              ##
###############################################################################################
//Get global var $config... In there are the names for the options
global $config;
//Calling Global Array $config...
$options = $config["Indexer"]["Modules"]; //In here are the diffrent options
//Now creating options wheel...
$options_wheel = "";
if (!$only_modules) {
    $options_wheel = "<select id=\"" . $curr_path . "_select\" size=\"1\" onchange=\"changeHidBySelect('" . $curr_path . "')\">";
}
$default_set = 0;
foreach ($options as $key => $value) {


    $options_wheel .= "<option value=\"" . $options[$key]["Class"] . "\"";
    if ($options[$key]["Class"] == $defaultvalue) { //in $options[$key]["Class"] are the values saved, e.g. "nr2"
        $options_wheel .= " selected=\"selected\"";
        $default_set = 1;
    }
    $options_wheel .= ">" . $options[$key]["Class"] . "<";
    $options_wheel .= ($only_modules ? "\\" : "");
    $options_wheel .= "/option>";        

} 
if (!$only_modules) {
    $options_wheel = $options_wheel . "
    </select><input type=\"hidden\" id=\"" . $curr_path . "_hidvalue\" name=\"" . $curr_path . "_hidvalue\" value=\"" . $defaultvalue . "\" />
    ";
}
if (($default_set == 0)&&($default_important == true)) {
    $options_wheel .= "*";
} 
return $options_wheel;
```

}

And if I call this function now, I call it like this:

```
echo createOptions($value4,$options_path,true,false);
```

$value4 is the defaultvalue, for upper example this would be "nr1"

So, and if I watch the code now with firebug or as source, there is sometimes a selected="selected" which works, but in other cases there is one which simply not works, and the first element is shown.

Comment: Is it working On the first page request perhaps? Have you got something to determine postback and then doing something different as a result?

Comment: Could you describe those cases in more details (the working and non working)? Don't forget to mention browser info, ... Remember that more details you provide better answers you would get.

Comment: So, now its quite edited ;) and @brumScouse, i'm not using something like postback or such, i'm just putting out the text, thats all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So guys, another question self-solved within one hour while posting. I just found why:

I'm calling after all displaying a JS function, which manipulates a div next to this div with the select in it, and it seem to change it somehow. So but now if I disabled this function, it worked perfectly. So I'll edit this function now ;) thx for help